How does Dolphin (KDE) synchronize with terminal window? Can this work with a tmux session?
I like to use Dolphin with a terminal session in the split window pane at the bottom. Key is that a cd command in the terminal changes the directory content being displayed in the Dolphin file view.
A while ago I started to used a tmux in all my terminal session. When I cd in the tmux pane, the file view in Dolphin does not follow. The other way round, this works: when I change the directory with the mouse, a corresponding cd command is run in the terminal.
This made me realize that I don't know how Dolphin keeps track of the current active directory in the terminal?
Is there a way to either make Dolphin track the current directory in the active tmux pane, or is there some type of command that could be executed from within the tmux pane to sync dolphin with the current working directory? I would not mind triggering this manually, or with a tmux key binding that I define. But to implement this I would need some basic understanding on how this interaction works.
I am using Dolphin version 21.12.3.
